Classifying acoustic drone signal, which notably has multiple consistent dominant frequencies over time
I'm trying to build a basic drone live audio classifier, without much signal processing knowledge.
Notably, The drone audio spectrum has multiple notable peaks which are continuous over time.
The frequencies may vary by model and by motion, but are consistent while the drone is still.
This example from a drone audio machine learning paper may explain it better:


Figure 3. Top: Spectrogram of the audio signal capturing a drone’s acoustic signature (drone model: ‘HP-X4 2020’; drone class: C3) during the outdoor experiment. Bottom: Classification results over time, showing the classifier’s predictions (based on the 2nd classifier with seed 1 in Table 3).


The spectrogram in the upper section of Figure 3 clearly illustrates a typical acoustic footprint of the drone’s activity. The typical acoustic spectrum of a drone is characterized by a distinctive pattern of harmonics across mid to high frequencies, often with peaks in lower frequencies generated by the rotors and motors. The drone initiated movement at around 7.5 s, with a stationary phase until approximately 25.5 s, and subsequently moved away from the microphone. Its farthest distance from the microphone, where the acoustic signature is weakest, was reached at around 52 s before it began its return journey. The drone passed directly overhead at 66.5 s and finally landed at 109 s.

Some other spectrogram examples which showcase the features:

I have done some research into audio classification in general and with drones specifically, and the vast majority is using generalized deep learning on spectrogram images.
The info is lacking for extracting specific features, or even non-ML detection methods.
I have mainly tried the following methods:

See whether there are spectrum peaks in expected frequency ranges, consistently over time. The ranges are manually set in settings.

This detected drones but has false positives. Felt like I was just measuring whether the spectrum has a lot of peaks, which is a feature of many different sounds.

Deep learning similar to various projects found in the internet. Most of them use CNNs or other models over spectrograms generated from audio, with a low regard to features, and multiple labels other than 'drone' or 'background'.

This hasn't worked too well yet, however I have not finished trying one with the largest database of 20GB.
As I am not an expert in ML classification either, it's also unclear to me whether to use many labels or only 'drone' and 'other' labels.
Are there other ways to extract features or detect drone sounds using the unique audio footprint?
